# prepareforSegue method on UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I used two `tableviewcontrollers`,i want to display country names array data in 
first `tableviewcontroller` (`recipeBookTableViewController`) and other capital array data in second `tableviewcontroller` (`RecipetableviewController`),
when a first `tableviewcontroller` cell is clicked it should move to second `tableviewcontroller` with capital array data.

I have taken `prepareforSegue` method to shift to second `tableview`. but the method is never called.
how to send data to next `tableview`.

```
RecipeBookViewController(table1)            Recipetableview(table2)
  INDIA (cell)                    ------------>      Delhi(cell)



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) 
   {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


      RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
      destViewController.second = [onew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      NSLog(@"%@",onew);
      NSLog(@"data is %@",destViewController.second);
      //  destViewController.lable2 = [derivationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      //  destViewController.image = [iconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in creating segue.

Make sure you have created segue from **cell of first table to second viewController**.

Name the segue as `showRecipeDetail`.

Look at the image below:
[image]

Comment: thank for replay but could you please explain how to solve this problem

Comment: Answer is itself an explanation. @PavanAlapati